# Obtener datos relacionas con Eloquent laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

Estoy haciendo es ta consulta la cual devuelve y status con las tareas asignadas a cada status

```
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $status = Status::with('tasks')
        ->get();
        return view('dashboard', compact('user', 'status'));
    }
```

Trabaja bien, me trae los datos relacionados entre las dos tablas, pero me gustaría saber como podría hacer un `where` con una columna de la tabla `task` las tabla `task` tiene un campo llamado `User_id` es decir algo así

```
 $status = Status::with('tasks')
           ->where(tasks.user_id, Auth::id())
           ->get();
```

para obtener solo las tareas que pertenecen a ese usuario

ahora mismo regresa

```
   [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Nueva",
    "created_at": "2020-03-19 17:31:36",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-19 17:31:36",
    "tasks": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Prof. Cooper Zboncak",
        "status_id": 1,
        **"user_id": 10,**
        "descripcion": "In quisquam natus ipsam quis",
        "created_at": "2020-03-19 17:31:39",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-19 17:31:39"
    }]
 }]
```

pero devuelve todas las tareas y me gustaría solo devolver los del usuario autenticado

actualmente hago una condicional en la vista

```
@foreach($status->tasks as $task)
   @if ($task->user_id == $user->id)
      <li class="text-row ui-sortable-handle" data-task-id="{{$task->id}}" style="">{{$task->name}} 
      </li>
   @endif
```

@endforeach
 y me muestra el resultado que espero

Comment: Has intentado hacer algo así? `$status->tasks()->where('user_id', 10)->get();`?

Comment: si ya lo intente `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statuses` where `user_id` = 1)`

Comment: Tienes ambas relaciones? Cuando usas `hasMany` en tu modelo, también debes hacer referencia en el otro modelo con `belongsTo`, tienes ambas bien relacionadas?

Comment: Intentare este `belongsTo`

Comment: mi modelo esta así `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Task;

class Status extends Model
{
   function tasks() {
     return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
 }

}`

Comment: Y tu modelo de `Task` cómo está?

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Status;


class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'status_id', 'user_id', 'descripcion', 'project', 'order', 'prioridad'
    ];
    function status() {
     return $this->belongsTo(Status::class)
    }

}`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105777/discussion-between-l-flor-and-daniel).